# Laravel eloquent relationships 3rd level

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

tables :

```
divisions
    id      name

districts
    id      division_id         name

subdistricts
    id      district_id         name


class Division extends Model
{
    //
    public function districts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\District', 'division_id');
    }

    public function subdistricts()
    {
        // what will be here
    }

}
```

is it possible to get subdistricts by division_id without using division_id on subdistricts table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read about [`hasManyThrough()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relation. So, `subdisctricts()` will look like this:

```
public function subdisctricts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\SubDistrict', 'App\District');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hasManyThrough()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hasManyThrough) as recommended, the syntax for hasManyThrough is:

```
class Division extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Subdistrict', 'App\District',
            'country_id', 'user_id', 'id'
        );
    }
}
```

The third argument is the name of the `foreign key on the intermediate model`, the fourth argument is the name of the `foreign key on the final model`, and the fifth argument is the `local key` -- [See Docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hasManyThrough)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) for this relation.

```
public function subdisctricts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Subdistrict', 'App\District');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try [`hasManyThrough()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) as:

```
public function subdistricts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Subdistrict', 'App\District');
}
```

> The `has-many-through` relationship provides a convenient short-cut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation.